Path based routing for AppRunner
I am trying to do a simple POC with app-runner. Lets assume we have simple microservices as part of our application.
Say
book-service

user-service.

Both are running fine in app-runner. This app-runner provides some urls for me to access within my VPC as shown below.

book-service: https://book.myregion.awsapprunner.com/
user-service:  https://user.myregion.awsapprunner.com/

But I would like to route the requests based on the path.
https://my-alb/user -> https://user.myregion.awsapprunner.com/user
https://my-alb/book -> https://book.myregion.awsapprunner.com/book

Problem:
ALB will use Target Groups. I could not get these Apprunner services under target group. So I could not use ALB.
Can anyone share any idea on how to achieve this?


Looks like it is not possible - https://github.com/aws/apprunner-roadmap/issues/223
